# google spreadsheet script, copy the value of a cell to another variable cell

Tags: copy, cell, spreadsheet

can I copy the value of a cell to another cell that is not always the same?

example:

```
 cal.getRange('B15').copyTo(cal.getRange('C25'));
```

but  the destination is not always C25, the destination is calculated and depend on three cells (checkin checkout and room number).
I would like to fill as many cells as there are days in a period of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
sheet.getRange(range).setValues(value);
```

This can be a 2d array depending on your range

in your case:

```
cal.getRange('C25').setValue(cal.getRange.getValue('B15'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to change the cell and not the value. B1 B2 B3 and so on (the cell must be "B"&1 B&2...). Sorry for may bad english :(